Anyone know how to set Flags of bluetooth advertising data?
I tired to set Flags(0x01) of bluetooth advertising data.
But I cannot find Flags setting from menu advertise via bluetoothctl.
There is only manufacturer, UUID, name and etc.
Anyone know how to set the Flags data?
Thanks.

The 'Flags' are automatically configured according to the Bluetooth hardware used and the configuration of the Bluetooth stack used. Changes to the content of this structure are therefore only possible to a very limited extent.
